# Trouble with finding Jira status changes since yesterday

Tags: jira, jql

In our current Jira setup (Jira 8.13.10), that I cannot influence btw, I need to find issues that changed to a specific status since yesterday for a board filter.

I came up with this JQL

```
status in (Closed, Done) AND status was not in (Closed, Done) BEFORE startOfDay(-1d)
```

which did not give the result I expected. Running this query in a quick filter on a Jira board with 4 different projects returns the issues closed since yesterday for 3 out of 4 projects and if I want to somewhat achieve my desired outcome (returning closed issues for all project on the board), I have to slightly modify the JQL to

```
status in (Closed, Done) AND status was not in (Closed, Done) BEFORE startOfDay(-28h)
```

To clarify, the problematic project (#4) had at least two issues that were closed at the same time (to the minute) as one of the projects that had its stories show up on the board using the first filter. However, the stories from project #4 would not show up on the board unless I used the auto filter code in the second example.

Is there some magic per-project setting that defines startOfDay or am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: You don't say in which way the results were unexpected. Presumably there was an issue which had been transitioned which didn't appear? When was it transitioned exactly?

Comment: Thanks, I tried to clarify the outcome a bit and also added the preconditions.

Answer (score 0):

`startOfDay()` will return the start of the day as defined by your user's `Time Zone`. This can be set on a per user basis on the `User Profile` page and, by default, will be set to follow the applications default timezone.
You will hopefully find that by updating your timezone, you achieve your expected results.

If the default timezone of your server is different to that of the majority of your userbase, I would suggest contacting a site admin and requesting that change, as it can impact reporting.

This of course is unavoidable if your userbase spans multiple timezones, in which case I might suggest picking the most convenient timezone for the majority and asking everyone to think in terms of that timezone when using the application.

If reporting isn't important to your organisation or individual reports won't span multiple timezones, then you will be fine to have individual user timezones, but just keep it in mind when sharing anything JQL based with other user's.

Comment: I don't see how this suggestion would address the problem that one out of four projects on the board, for the same user, is not displayed as expected.

Comment: @RogerMagnesved, this answer was based on your original question, and was my best guess as to what could be going on. Based on your edits, I don't think there is much more I could suggest without further information. Maybe the tickets in project 4 had been transitioned to a done status type then back to an in progress status before being finally closed? I'd probably suggest getting a professional to take a look directly at your problem and work it out, if you can't think of any more details to include in the question.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into if there were any unusual transitions on said stories.